# how to update ruby path?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, path

I'm reinstalling ruby with proper instructions this time
but I have paths messed up

this is what I'm getting this error

```
Last login: Sun Feb 24 02:06:37 on ttys000
Fawads-MacBook-Pro:~ fawadnaseer$ rvm install 1.9.3
Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
No binary rubies available for: osx/10.8/x86_64/ruby-1.9.3-p374.
Continuing with compilation. Please read 'rvm mount' to get more information on binary rubies.
Installing Ruby from source to: /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p374, this may take a while depending on your cpu(s)...
ruby-1.9.3-p374 - #downloading ruby-1.9.3-p374, this may take a while depending on your connection...
######################################################################## 100.0%
ruby-1.9.3-p374 - #extracting ruby-1.9.3-p374 to /usr/local/rvm/src/ruby-1.9.3-p374
ruby-1.9.3-p374 - #extracted to /usr/local/rvm/src/ruby-1.9.3-p374
ruby-1.9.3-p374 - #configuring
Error running 'env LDFLAGS=-L/opt/sm/pkg/active/lib CFLAGS=-I/opt/sm/pkg/active/include CPATH=/opt/sm/pkg/active/include ./configure --disable-install-doc --prefix=/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p374 --with-opt-dir=/usr/local/rvm/usr --disable-shared', please read /usr/local/rvm/log/ruby-1.9.3-p374/configure.log
There has been an error while running configure. Halting the installation.
```

Configure.log file contents

here is the configure.log file
[2013-02-24 02:09:37] ./configure
current path: /usr/local/rvm/src/ruby-1.9.3-p374
command(7): env LDFLAGS=-L/opt/sm/pkg/active/lib CFLAGS=-I/opt/sm/pkg/active/include CPATH=/opt/sm/pkg/active/include ./configure --disable-install-doc --prefix=/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p374 --with-opt-dir=/usr/local/rvm/usr --disable-shared
checking build system type... x86_64-apple-darwin12.2.1
checking host system type... x86_64-apple-darwin12.2.1
checking target system type... x86_64-apple-darwin12.2.1
checking for C compiler default output file name... 
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables

**UPDATE:**

Ok guys I have RVM installed
Ruby Installed
Rails Installed

what when i put echo $PATH

echo $PATH
/Users/fawadnaseer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/bin:/Users/fawadnaseer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/bin:/Users/fawadnaseer/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/bin:/Users/fawadnaseer/.rvm/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin

**are there any problem in this path?**

Comment: read the error message. it says to look into /usr/local/rvm/log/ruby-1.9.3-p374/configure.log

Comment: What makes you think this is a path issue?

Comment: I m totally a newbie.. 

because I was following this tutorial on lynda.. and the guy asked me to update the paths.. but it didnt work out .. sql stuff .. 

so i think the path has been messed up


Update: So guys rvm is installed.
I used sudo gem install rails.. now its installing rails.

Comment: @rubii: I have updated my question with configure.log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the clang compiler instead of the default:

`rvm install 1.9.3 --with-gcc=clang`

Comment: really appreciated for your response! 
I'm really messed up here

I have Jewellery Box installed on MAC if you know about jewellery box. it sets up RVM 
and and ruby too..

so i have installed this 

bernard this is what i'm getting now 
"Already installed ruby-1.9.3-p392.
To reinstall use:

    rvm reinstall 1.9.3"


now I used this sudo gem install rails "now installing rails" a minute ago it was giving me error :\

Comment: If you have it already installed then you can call: `rvm reinstall 1.9.3 --with-gcc=clang`.